# nothing happens when the batch file is executed

Tags: c#, batch-file

I write Unit test on c#. I have batch file. And In code I need execute it. But nothing happens. Why? Can I log batch command? My batch file:

```
cd c:\Publish\Test
tf workspace /new blah2 /noprompt /collection:http://servertfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ /login:SERVERTFS\Administrator,password
tf workfold /map $/ . /login:SERVERTFS\Administrator,password
tf get "$/Somepath" /force /recursive 
tf workspace /delete /noprompt blah2
```

Program execute batch file next code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\name.bat");
```

Comment: Well how are you *trying* to execute the batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether there is a typo in `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\name.bat");` if it is,then you shall change to `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\name.bat");` or `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\name.bat");`